# MySql: Difference two columns returned by multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, query-performance, set-difference

I have a DB that has a bunch of businesses and the relationships between them.  I am trying to find a way to get all Businesses that B2 sells to that B1 does not sell too.  But Only on B2 where B1 and B2 sell to the same business.

V= Vendor, C = Client,  Both are businesses but thinking in terms of Vendor/Client makes this easier to explain.

V1 -sells to-> C1 <- sells to- V2 -sells to-> C2

I am looking for all C2 that are not also in C1 for a specific V1 starting point.

My current tables:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE business;  
+---------------+-------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| Field         | Type              | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| business_id   | int(11)           | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment |
| email         | varchar(255)      | YES  |     |          |                |
| name          | varchar(255)      | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| city          | varchar(255)      | YES  |     |          |                |
| state         | varchar(255)      | YES  | MUL |          |                |
| cCount        | int(10) unsigned  | YES  | MUL | 0        |                |
| scCount       | int(10) unsigned  | YES  | MUL | 0        |                |
| vCount        | int(10) unsigned  | YES  | MUL | 0        |                |
| svCount       | int(10) unsigned  | YES  | MUL | 0        |                |
+---------------+-------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE relation_sells_to;
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+--------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra  |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+--------+
| start   | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |        |
| end     | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |        |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+--------+

mysql> DESCRIBE vcvc;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| vendor  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| client  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| vendor2 | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| client2 | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I can use these two queries to get up to date results, But I have to drop the vcvc table every time I want to update it and it currently takes 15 min to build it.  I also will not need access to all that info at any one time.  I may need to generate theses lists for a few thousand at a time but not the full DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vcvc (INDEX vendor (vendor), INDEX client2 (client2))
SELECT r.start AS vendor, r.end AS client, r2.start AS vendor2, r3.end AS client2
FROM relation_sells_to AS r
JOIN relation_sells_to as r2 ON r.end = r2.end
JOIN relation_sells_to AS r3 ON r2.start = r3.start
WHERE r.start != r2.start
AND r.end != r3.end;

SELECT DISTINCT(client2), cCount, scCount, vCount, svCount 
FROM vcvc 
JOIN business AS b ON client2=b.business_id 
WHERE vendor = #### 
AND client2 NOT IN (SELECT client FROM vcvc WHERE vendor = ####) 
ORDER BY cCount DESC;
```

Is there a way to do this in a single query so I dont have to build a whole new table every time I need to get this information?  I currently have 500k relations and when I build this table I end up with over 100 million rows and most of those I don't need.  Ideally I would be able to take an email(preferred) or business_id as the starting business/vendor, then just return a list of  Business/clients with name, city, state, cCount, vCount and have them order in DESC order by vCount and probably LIMIT 20ish.  Speed isn't a huge issue I really just want to be able to get current results without having to build a large table of which I need 20 of the 100+millions rows on it.  I originally tried working with a temp table but because I cant "reopen" the temp table like my current query needs.

Thanks for the help.

Update with sample data and desired output.
Some of the cCount and vCounts might be off,  I copied real data then modified it but I don't know if I updated all the numbers correctly as I added the required connections to show what I need.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM business;
+-------------+----------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| business_id | email          | name                 | city           | state      | cCount | scCount | vCount | svCount |
+-------------+----------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|        1    | bob@bob.com    | Bobs Construction    | Virginia Beach | Virginia   |     62 |       3 |      0 |       0 |
|        2    | sue@bob.com    | Upholstery by Sue    | Austin         | Texas      |     20 |       3 |      4 |       4 |
|        3    | jim@bob.com    | Jim & Associates     | Crowley        | Texas      |      5 |       3 |      0 |       0 |
|        4    | jon@bob.com    | Jon Jon architects   | Costa Mesa     | California |     67 |       3 |      0 |       0 |
|        5    | joe@bob.com    | Joes Pizza           | Hamden         | Conecticut |     7  |       1 |      0 |       0 |
|        6    | tim@bob.com    | Tims WIndows         | Miami          | Florida    |     10 |       2 |      0 |       0 |
|        7    | ron@bob.com    | Rons Hot Rods        | Costa Mesa     | California |     8  |       4 |      0 |       0 |
+-------------+----------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+---------+

mysql> SELECT start, end FROM relation_sells_to;
+-------+--------+
| start | end    |
+-------+--------+
|  3    | 1      |
|  3    | 2      |
|  2    | 4      |
|  2    | 5      |
|  4    | 2      |
|  1    | 5      |
|  4    | 5      |
|  4    | 6      |
|  4    | 7      |
+-------+--------+

-- Run code to build vcvc table.  Code is above.

mysql> SELECT * FROM vcvc WHERE vendor = 3;
+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| vendor | client | vendor2 | client2 |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+
|   3    | 1      |  2      |    4    |
|   3    | 1      |  2      |    5    |
|   3    | 1      |  4      |    2    |
|   3    | 2      |  1      |    5    |
|   3    | 2      |  4      |    5    |
|   3    | 2      |  4      |    6    |
|   3    | 2      |  4      |    7    |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+

Desired Output:

Select client_id, name, city, state, cCount, vCount FROM MAGIC WHERE email = jim@bob.com
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+
| client_id | name                | city           | state      | cCount | vCount  |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+
|   4       | Jon Jon architects  | Costa Mesa     | California |     67 |       0 |
|   6       | Tims WIndows        | Miami          | Florida    |     10 |       0 |
|   7       | Rons Hot Rods       | Costa Mesa     | California |     8  |       0 |
|   5       | Joes Pizza          | Hamden         | Conecticut |     7  |       0 |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+
-- Ordered by cCount, business_id 2 is NOT in this list because 3 sells to 2 so I don't care that 4 sells to 2.
```

UPDATE 2:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdcec/2

Here is a fiddle of it.  The data in the fiddle is slightly different than the data above in that it has 2-3 more connections to properly show what I want.

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output. That will help a lot.

Comment: Added some sample data.  Hope that helps.  If any of it doesnt make sense let me know and Ill try and fix/explain any part of it.

Comment: vcvc *looks* like poor design

Comment: @Strawberry Not gonna argue there.  I'm trying to figure out a way to eliminate the need for that table.

Comment: Also note that DISTINCT is not a function, but also thanks - I didnt know you could index a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement in that way.

Comment: Can you provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) and the desired result?

Comment: @Strawberry here is a sqlfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdcec/2) Ive never used sqlfiddle so I hope it all works right.  It seems kind of slow for me.  I tried to use real data with names swapped out but it got too large too fast for sqlfiddle.  So I reused the example from above with a little tweaking to try and show what I wanted.  My desired result is at the bottom, I just want to get that without needing to use/create the vcvc table at all.